# Deployment of Visual Studio Add-in in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

I have created Visual studio add-in successfully.But I am confused to deploy this addin in another computers.I have go throgh the stackoverflow answers.But I did not get clear cut idea about this matter

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy YourAddIn.dll and YourAddIn.AddIn files to "c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins\" folder on another computer. To create an installer you can start with [Wix Template For VS2012 Addin Project](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/491dc26d-90b0-4e0d-a45e-4281d93f81c6).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have copied  addin dll into addins folder.But  it shows an error message "The Addin failed to load or caused an exception".

Comment: @VipinRT Maybe your add-in depends on additional dlls? If yes, copy them into the Addis folder as well.

Comment: I am using 64 bit operating system.It worked perfectly when the addin dll and other dependent dlls are copied into addin folder on 64 bit systems.But it does not work in x86 systems

Answer (score 0):

Deploying an add-in requires to copy the add-in dll(s) to some folder and create a XML .AddIn file in a predefined folder where VS can locate it where a entry of the XML file points to the add-in assembly.

For articles about the prefedined folders for .AddIn files and about creating a setup see the "Articles about installing and uninstalling" section of my web site:

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/

To troubleshoot problems loading add-ins see my article:

[HOWTO: Troubleshooting Visual Studio and Office add-ins](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007009.aspx)

Visual Studio is a 32-bit executable, so the add-in dll and dependencies must be 32-bit.