# How to package a Visual Studio Add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-addins

I've created a Visual Studio Add-in. Now I would like to create a deployable package so that other users could install the add-in on their machine. How could I do so?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418694/deployment-of-visual-studio-add-in-in-vs-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying an add-in requires to copy the add-in dll(s) to some folder and create a XML .AddIn file in a predefined folder where VS can locate it where a entry of the XML file points to the add-in assembly.

For articles about the prefedined folders for .AddIn files and about creating a setup see the "Articles about installing and uninstalling" section of my web site:

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/